# positioning works in ff,chrome but not in ie7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7, positioning

I have some divs which i positioned with

```
position:absolute;
width:100px;
margin:-20px 420px;
```

same like this another one also...
the problem is it is looking fine in chrome and firefox ,but in ie7 those divs are being moved away.
how to set it to look perfect in all browsers??thanks
edited:

```
.button {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background:url(../images/portfolio.gif) no-repeat 0 -49px;
  margin:-50px 420px;
}
.button a {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(../images/portfolio.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
.button a:hover {
  background-position: 0 50px;
}


.button1 {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background:url(../images/design-brief.gif) no-repeat 0 -49px;
  margin:-20px 420px;
}
.button1 a {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:url(../images/design-brief.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
.button1 a:hover {
  background-position: 0 50px;
}
```

these two buttons,button and button1 are inside this div along with some text

```
.cont
{
position:relative;
width:1400px;
height:500px;

}
```

Comment: Can you post a live example, and the rest of the relevant code? We need to see how this div interacts with others (What it's postioned absolutely relative to) :) You can use jsFiddle.net if you can't supply an example on your own server.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "moved away"? Are they moving at all but slightly off? Are the massively off? Could you post some code from the HTML?

Comment: edited my code..pls check all

Comment: I understand negative margins higher than <div> height are problematic..!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to set a `top:0px` and a `left:0px`. You can not use `position:absolute` without setting a real position.

Or: You can try `position:static` or `position:relative`, I'm not sure what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin to position your buttons. If you have made it `position:absolute;` use `top: 0px; left: 0px;` (obviously setting them to the desired position). As you have set the parent div `.cont` as `position:relative;` the buttons will be set within this div as long as they are there in the DOM. So if you were to set them `top: 0px; left: 0px;` the buttons would sit in the top left hand corner of the div.

Much more reliable than playing with negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Matt Asbury... If u r using positions then there is no use of margins. and one more thing, u r using position absolute for buttons. in that case don't use position for its child unless and until u want to position its child as well. If u can provide html then it will be easy to understand the code and help.